# cssClassApplier only on selected text in specified divs

Tags: javascript, textselection, rangy

I'm trying to add classes to selected text in a document. The problem is that I don't want the user to be able to select ALL the text on the page (using command+A for example...) So I would like to remove nodes from a range but I don't know how to do that. This page has a lot of text / nested divs so using the added class for checking if it is in an element that is selectable would be very time consuming / slow.

I made a fiddle to explain what I'm trying to do a bit better. 
http://jsfiddle.net/thomasjonas/BhKFt/20/

If you select all the text in this example the class is added to all the divs. I want it to only apply the css to the divs with the 'yes' class. Is there a nice, non-browser-crashing solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a little heavy-handed and inefficient because it checks each element with class "yes" intersects the selection. You could improve it by checking in advance whether the selection lies completely within a single element with the "yes" class, for example. It uses Rangy's proprietary `intersection()` method of range objects.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/BhKFt/23/

Code:

```
// getElementsByClassName implementation for browsers without it
// (IE <= 7, for example)
var getElementsByClassName =
    (typeof document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName != "undefined") ?

    function(el, cssClass) {
        return el.getElementsByClassName(cssClass);
    } :
    function(el, cssClass) {
        var allEls = el.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var elsWithClass = [];
        var classRegex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + cssClass + "(?:\\s|$)");
        for (var i = 0, len = allEls.length, el; i < len; ++i) {
            el = allEls[i];
            if (el.className && classRegex.test(el.className)) {
                elsWithClass.push(el);
            }
        }
        return elsWithClass;
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    rangy.init();
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        var sel = rangy.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var classApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("tmp");

        var els = getElementsByClassName(document.body, "yes");

        // Create an array of ranges that represent the intersection of
        // the selection with each "yes" element
        var rangesWithClass = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = els.length, elRange; i < len; ++i) {
            if (range.intersectsNode(els[i])) {
                elRange = rangy.createRange();
                elRange.selectNode(els[i]);
                rangesWithClass.push(range.intersection(elRange));
                elRange.detach();
            }
        }

        // Apply the class to the ranges obtained in the last step
        for (i = 0, len = rangesWithClass.length; i < len; ++i) {
            classApplier.applyToRange(rangesWithClass[i]);
            rangesWithClass[i].detach();
        }

        sel.removeAllRanges();
    });
});
```

It may be useful if there was some kind of filtering option to the options object passed into `rangy.createCssClassApplier()`. I'll have a think.

Comment: Hi Tim,

thanks so much for answering my question... I'm sorry I didn't respond earlier... I guess I have turned off notifications... The code is going to be implemented in a pretty heavy site so I'm hoping your solution will help...

In the mean time I came up with another solution which collapses the selection if it isn't valid (that means, when there is a 'no' class selected). That code can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasjonas/CM2wJ/